# ¿Por qué el navegador pone un espacio después de un carácter con tilde?

Tags: utf-8

En una página que estoy probando a hacer, el navegador añade un espacio después de los caracteres con tilde, aunque inspeccionando el elemento, ese espacio no existe.

He probado con varios navegadores y siempre igual.

La codificación que anuncio es *UTF-8*, idioma *es_ES*, 
¿Alguna idea?

Imagen como muestra el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen como muestra el inspector de código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

! Actualizo: he probado todas y cada uno de los comentarios, nada me ha funcionado. Pero he comprobado como al escribir el texto en mayúsculas ocurre exactamente lo contrario, el carácter siguiente al de tilde se superpone. Es decir, parece que la interpretación de ese espacio está cambiada entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Imagen como muestra las mayúsculas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por si ayuda de alguna forma, esta es la fuente que utilizo:

http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Neutra-Display-Medium-Alt

Comment: Usa esa misma fuente en otro sitio porque a lo mejor la fuente usa más distancia después de caractéres con **tildes** (off-topic: hay muchos tipos de acentos, tilde es el acento gráfico que es lo que quieres decir)

Comment: Tilde, perdón. He probado con otras fuentes (con el mismo resultado) y con esa misma en otro sitio (y se ve correctamente), no es algo propio de la fuente, parece que tenga que ver con la codificación, pero también es correcta.

Comment: Pon mas datos. Trozo del archivo .html, .php o .js que genera el problema. Si lo generas dinamico, revisa las cabeceras que envías. Es una *funcionalidad* interesante la que te ocurre.

Comment: Tienes que pegar aquí tu fragmento de código donde te pasa eso para que podamos ejecutarlo desde la web a ver si hay algo más que no sabemos.

Comment: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios, pero de nada serviría añadir código. ¿o te sirve de algo esto? <h2>plástico</h2>, también he probado <h2>pl&aacute;stico</h2> con el mismo resultado.

Comment: Asumo, pues, que es el contenido de un .html estático, que no generas tu con PHP, ni con Node.js, ni nada ? un .html plano, sin Javascript que genere el contenido ni cambie nada ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solución:
especificando la fuente en varios formatos ya no se da el problema, lo dejo a continuación por si a alguien le pudiese servir:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
@font-face {font-family: 'Neutra-light';
src: url('fonts/neutradisplay-medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/fonts/neutradisplay-medium.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/fonts/neutradisplay-medium.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('/fonts/neutradisplay-medium.svg#NeutraDisplayMedium') format('svg');
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de `á`, y otros caracteres raros, prueba a poner `entidades`.

Cambia la `á` por `&atilde;`, es decir, `pl&atilde;stico`

Otro posible origen del problema son las fuentes. Tal vez **el navegador** y solo **el navegador** use una fuente por defecto sin ese caracter.

Y, por no descartar nada, asegúrate de que el sistema tiene correctamente configurado el idioma.

Otra cosa: ¿ como colocas ese texto ? ¿ en el `.html` plano, o lo colocas con `Javascript` ? ¿ Usas alguna librería para establecer ese texto ? Se me han dado casos de que colocando el texto directamente, no había problema, pero utilizando librerías, si (especificamente, la `webix`, creo que en su función `message` ). Y no hubo forma, tuve que cambiar la palabra xD.

Comment: gracias, he probado con &aacute; pero sigue apareciendo igual, en el código correctamente y en el navegador con un espacio después de la tilde.

Comment: Intenta cambiando la fuente del navegador, por si la que usa por defecto no tuviese ese caracter (aunque otras en tu sistema si lo tengan).

Answer (score 0):

pone en la cabecera de tu html esto

> `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />`